# Flutter - how to keep track of corners and lines of a shape after transformation

Tags: flutter, paint

i'm fairly new to flutter.

The app i'm trying to develop allows the user to create simple shapes that can be transformed (scaled/rotated/translated) but also be able to select the corners and lines, therefore the position of the corners and lines must be known.

The app must also allow for multiple shapes to be present at any one time and each shape can be transformed individually.

I have been trying to use the canvas.drawPath in a customPainter, and can successfully transform
each shape as desired using a matrix4 array, but i'm not sure how to monitor the position of the corners after transformation.

I'd really appreciate any advice as i'm quite stuck on this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using MatrixUtils.transformPoint which returns the new Offset after the transformation.

The complete shape is just a list of Offsets so i just applied the transformPoint for each element using the .forEach.

worked for me.